# Excel Group feature - inserting rows

Tags: excel, row, grouping, excel-2010

I'm working with Excel 2010, using the Group feature to collapse (and then show) groups of rows.

This works well until the point that I insert additional rows copied from another worksheet. Choosing the shift cells down option also moves the start and end point of the grouping - effectively breaking the grouping that I want.

My question is - can I keep the groupings AND insert new rows (automatically expanding the rows in the particular group)?

Answer (score 3):

You can insert rows into a group without breaking the grouping as long as you don't insert them into the last row of the group.

Select the point within the group to insert (select a single cell) user the context menu to insert cells.